# Could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm running an example in R, going through the steps and everything is working so far except for this code produces an error:

```
View(WhatsApp.Chat.with.Yaswanth)
history <- "WhatsApp.Chat.with.Yaswanth.txt"

chat_clean <- chat_clean %>%
   filter(!word %in% to_remove)
```

> Error in chat_clean %>% filter(!word %in% to_remove) :
> could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Run `library(dplyr)` first.

Comment: must be a duplicate, although searching is hard ...